# Flowfram left frame flowing between pages

Tags: flowfram

Werner provided the code below which works.  My question is how to continue the left side bar text to the next page.  In other words, I want the right main body text to flow between pages exactly as his code allows, but I also want the left sidebar text to flow between pages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{flowfram,lipsum}

\newstaticframe[1]{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}{0pt}{.75\textheight}[top]
\newstaticframe[1]{.3\textwidth}{.72\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
\setallstaticframes{valign=t}

\newflowframe[1]{.65\textwidth}{.72\textheight}{.35\textwidth}{0pt}
\newflowframe[2]{.65\textwidth}{\textheight}{.35\textwidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{staticcontents*}{top}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{staticcontents*}{left}
\raggedright\lipsum[3-4]
\end{staticcontents*}

\lipsum[1-10]% right column the can overflow

\end{document}
```

Comment: Static frames don't permit text to flow across frames. Only the "flow" frames allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for paracol!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}

\columnsep=0.05\textwidth
\setcolumnwidth{.3\textwidth,.65\textwidth}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[c][0.25\textheight][t]{\textwidth}% to set height=0.25\textheight
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\raggedright\lipsum[3-4]
\switchcolumn
\parindent=\bibindent% if desired
\lipsum[1-10]% right column the can overflow
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfect!  Thx!

Comment: If an answer is acceptable, the custom is to click the check mark and move this from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Answers finding solutions to paracol problems are underappreciated in general, imho. Such a wonderful package (as far as I cal tell from my limited experience with it), but the documentation is quite the challenge to read.